# Switching into (Linux) Kernel Mode

Tags: linux, network-programming, linux-kernel

Linux n00b here. How does one switch from User Mode to Kernel Mode? I'm running Linux Ubuntu 12.10. Is there an interrupt that I can call using inline assembly code that will do this? If not, how can it be done?

I'm asking this question because I am wishing to write a SCTP (network)protocol stack which has access to the kernel and runs in the background constantly though the UI cannot directly access the kernel. Never done anything like this before so tips from pros would definitely be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

All switches to kernel mode are made via system calls. In the case of network protocols these system calls are socket, listen, accept, ioctl, read, write, recvmsg, etc.

You write a Linux kernel module. There is already a SCTP protocol stack for Linux though. You would likely be better off modifying it to do what you want.

Once you have written and compiled your module you can load it into the kernel using insmod and rmmod. In my experience you rarely get a chance to use rmmod because if you made a mistake the system crashes or freezes. So use a virtual machine for your testing. It is faster to reboot, you lose less data, and it is easier to hook up a virtual serial console for debugging.

I am sure this question is a duplicate by the way. You can find a lot of questions on this topic.

Comment: Linux AFAIK does not come with a built-in SCTP protocol stack, and neither does windows(all versions). I'm sure I can find it somewhere out there in cyberspace but creating my own from scavenged source code will be a good exercise and teach me about kernel stuff(which employers definitely want programmers to know).

Comment: There is ONLY 1 such protocol stack available for windows: SCTPdrv written by Bruce Cran and it has some MAJOR bugs in it! Trying to test SCTP applications by using the loopback address will crash the entire system and he is too lazy to fix it. But Windows kernel drivers are a whole 'nother kettle of fish as Windows is far more complex and not open source.

Comment: @MrX: My Ubuntu 12 has this: /lib/modules/3.2.0-43-generic/kernel/net/sctp/sctp.ko

Comment: Ha! Mine too. I guess I didn't know they were there. That makes things easier. I think I'll do the windows one instead.